# How to display Caps,Shift,Enter buttons when i focus on textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written the following code for a virtual keyboard using javascript.

Jsp page:

```
   <form>
        <label for="text">Enter Text: </label>
        <input id="text" name="text" type="text" size="50" onfocus="myFunction(this)" />
        <input name="" type="reset" value="Clear" />
     </form>
```

Javascript:

```
 function myFunction(x)
    {                    
    }

    function clicked(val)
    {   
        var txt;
        txt = document.getElementById('text').value;

        if(val != 'B')
        {
            txt = txt + '' + val;
        }
        else
        {
            txt = txt.substr(0,(txt.length)-1);
        }
        document.getElementById('text').value = txt;
    }
 $(".dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 200,
        width: 930,
        modal: false,
        draggable: true,
        resizable: true,

        buttons : {

                        "ESC":function(){
                var val="Esc";
                clicked(val);

            },

            "1":function(){
                var val="1";
                clicked(val);
            },

            "Tab":function(){
                var val="T";
                clicked(val);
            },
            "Caps":function(){
                var val="q";
                clicked(val);
            },




            "Shift":function(){
                var val="";
                clicked(val);
            },

            "B":function(){
                var val=" ";
                clicked(val);
            },





        },

});
```

When the text box is focused display dialog like keyboard, when i click some button its entered button value in textbox except Caps,Shift,Enter and Tab.

Please provide the required code for those Caps,Shift,Enter,Tab .

I'm not sure how to maintain code in clicked(val) method .

Answer (score 0):

When user presses shift/caps it would probably be better idea to set a flag instead of inserting anything to textbox. For example:

```
"Shift":function(){
                isShift=1;
            }
"Caps":function(){
                isCap=1;
            },
```

Then when it comes to inserting a letter check the flags. If `isShift` or `isCap` is set then insert capital letter. Also `isShift` should be set `0` then.

It's just PoC code, you will know how to implement it.

Comment: i want keyboard functionality,means when click Caps button after that i clicked one more button, the button value is capsuled